# PHP registration allow admin to create accounts

Tags: php, mysql, registration, accounts

I am developing an application where it will be necessary that during registration the user who registers becomes the "admin" for their group and then has the ability to create sub users who they can manage.

I plan on creating a table with the following fields: unique id; username; password; role and group.

I am uncertain best method to enable that the original account is auto tagged as the admin and has the ability to both create groups and have the sub groups tied to it.

The original question got tagged as not being right for the forum -- but I am not looking for how to code and more so best process.

Comment: did you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a boolean field "group_admin" in the table where these users are stored to control if the user can or cannot create other users. If group_admin equals true (or 1) he is able to manage the group. Did that help you?

Comment: Thanks -- that was enough to get me moving in the right direction.  Much appreciated.